# How to wait for forEach to complete when each iteration calls an asynchronous options?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, callback, promise

Alright, here's what the plan is. Go through each file, add the file into the array. Once all files are added, then combine them using the JSZipUtility and Docxtemplater:

```
'click .merge-icon': (e) => {
    var programId = Router.current().url.split('/').pop();
    var programObj = Programs.findOne(programId);
    var insertedDocuments = [];
    var i = 0;
    var count = programObj.activityIds.count;
    var fileDownloadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      programObj.activityIds.forEach(function(activityId) {
        var activityObj = Activities.findOne(activityId);
        var documentObj = ActivityFiles.findOne(activityObj.documents.pop()._id);
        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(documentObj.url(), callback);
        function callback(error, content) {
          var zip = new JSZip(content);
          var doc = new Docxtemplater().loadZip(zip);
          var xml = zip.files[doc.fileTypeConfig.textPath].asText();
          xml = xml.substring(xml.indexOf("<w:body>") + 8);
          xml = xml.substring(0, xml.indexOf("</w:body>"));
          xml = xml.substring(0, xml.indexOf("<w:sectPr"));
          insertedDocuments.push(xml);
          i++;
          if (i == count - 1) {
            resolve();
          }
        }
      });
    });
    fileDownloadPromise.then(() => {
      JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent('/assets/template.docx', callback);
      function callback(error, content) {
        console.log(content);
        var zip = new JSZip(content);
        var doc = new Docxtemplater().loadZip(zip);
        setData(doc);
      }

      function setData(doc) {
        doc.setData({
          body: insertedDocuments.join('<w:br/><w:br/>')
        });
        doc.render();
        useResult(doc);
      }

      function useResult(doc) {
        var out = doc.getZip().generate({
          type: 'blob',
          mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
        });
        saveAs(out, programObj.name + '.docx');
      }
    });
  }
```

Turns out nothing's happening. What's wrong with the execution of this Promise here ?

I'm only calling resolve when every file has been loaded in the array.

Comment: The obvious question, does `i == count - 1` ever evaluate to to `true`?

Comment: Didn't you want to download each file in its own promise and use Promise.all() to wait for them, then do the zipping.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli No. The callback that the condition is wrapped in is not called.

Comment: @marekful I can't wrap my head around Promise.all at all.

Comment: So the promise is largely irrelevant then. Figure out why the call to `getBinaryContent` doesn't trigger the callback. Is the url correct? Is `documentObject.url()` the correct thing to be calling? The callback should be called regardless even if there's an error, according to the docs.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli When not implemented in the Promise, `getBinaryContent` works just fine. The only problem is that the following functions execute before all the files are added to the `insertedDocuments` array and so ends up creating an empty file.

Comment: But you said "The callback that the condition is wrapped in is not called." Which is it?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli The resolve condition is the in the callback of this line: `JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(documentObj.url(), callback);`. When this is not declared in a Promise, the callback is called and the files are added to the array. Problem is that they're added asynchronously and the following functions don't wait for the array to be populated and create an empty file. What I want to do is to wait for the files to be added to the array and then call the file creation functions.

Comment: There is no way for the "following functions" to be called until the promise resolves. The only thing following the declaration of `fileDownloadPromise` can only run when `fileDownloadPromise` is resolved. I don't think you're painting the full picture here.